# How to create new json Array from 2 array with condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I have this first sample data

```
[{start : 1,end : 10 },
{start : 11,end : 20 },
{start : 21,end : 30 }]
```

And Second sample data

```
[{weight : 7,price : 20 },
  {weight : 8 ,price : 10},
  {weight : 11 ,price : 14}]
```

I'm trying to use for loop through my sample and check if weight is between what start and end. 
For example if 'weight : 7,price : 20 ' from second sample is between 'start : 1,end : 10' of first sample count would be 1 and sumPrice would be 20.

And next loop with 'weight : 8',price : 10, count will 1+1 and sumPrice is 20 + 10 from first time of loop. Then do the same.

My expected result would be like this

```
[{ start : 1,end : 10 ,count : 2 , sumPrice :  30},
{ start : 11,end : 20 ,count : 1 , sumPrice :  14 },
{ start : 21,end : 30 ,count : 0 , sumPrice :  0  }]
```

P.S. Sorry for my English skill and I'm new in javascript. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post at least a little bit of code to show what you tried so far.

Comment: Hello, share with us what you've tried and what issues are you facing, we expect some effort from you instead of writing all code

Comment: Whats the criteria for `count` and `sumPrice` values? Please, [edit] your question, let it more clear and show some effort/code

Comment: I think, id 1 starts at 1 and ends at 10, meaning it processes weight 7 and weigth 8; count equals 2 and sum is 20 + 14

Comment: Smells like homework by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is `map` over your conditional array, and then `reduce` your array of data.

```
const arr1 = [{_id : 1 , start : 1,end : 10 },
  {_id : 2 , start : 11,end : 20 },
  {_id : 3 , start : 21,end : 30 }];

const arr2 = [{weight : 7,price : 20 },
  {weight : 11 ,price : 10},
  {weight : 8 ,price : 14}];



const result = arr1.map((condition) => {
    return arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.weight >= condition.start && curr.weight <= condition.end) {
        return {
        ...acc,
        count: acc.count + 1,
        sumPrice: acc.sumPrice + curr.price,
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, {
    _id: condition._id,
    start: condition.start,
    end: condition.end,
    count: 0,
    sumPrice: 0,
  })
});

console.log(result);
```

```js
[{_id : 1 , start : 1,end : 10 ,count : 2 , sumPrice :  34},
{_id : 2 , start : 11,end : 20 ,count : 1 , sumPrice :  10 },
{_id : 3 , start : 21,end : 30 ,count : 0 , sumPrice :  0  }]
```

Comment: Thanks Brett . You save my day!!

Answer (score 0):

use **jsLinq** lib

> many useful methods here https://github.com/battousai999/js-linq

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (var i in ranges) {
    var range = ranges[i];
    
    // conditions
    var matchedItems = $linq(arr).where(r => r.weight >= range.start 
                                          && r.weight <= range.end
                                       ).toArray();

    // count matched
    var count = $linq(matchedItems).count(); 

    // sum price prop.
    var sum = $linq(matchedItems).sum(c => c.price); 

    range.count = count;
    range.sumPrice = sum;
  }

  console.log(ranges);
};


var ranges = [{_id : 1 , start : 1,end : 10 },
{_id : 2 , start : 11,end : 20 },
{_id : 3 , start : 21,end : 30 }];

var arr = [{weight : 7,price : 20 },
  {weight : 11 ,price : 10},
  {weight : 8 ,price : 14}];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-linq@1.6.0/jslinq.min.js"></script>
```